# JavaScript/Lodash/Angular 1 - Search in an object array and find a property

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ecmascript-6, lodash

I want to look in an array of objects if it contains a property and returns true if it found it, or false if it did not find it

An example of my array :
`this.realEstateProjectMotivation.realEstateProjectOnSales[0]` which is worth :

```
[
  {
    "id": 30,
    "satisfied": false,
    "onSaleSince":"1 day"
  }
]
```

I would like to look in if `realEstateProjectOnSales` it contains `onSaleSince` and `satisfied` properties

how can I do it using Lodash or EcmaScript 2015 for example ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to check if a property exists in an object. You can loop the array with [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to find if at least one object contains the properties:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "id": 30,
    "satisfied": false,
    "onSaleSince":"1 day"
  }
];

const containsProps = (item) => 'onSaleSince' in item && 'satisfied' in item;

const is0Contains = containsProps(arr[0]);

console.log('is0Contains: ', is0Contains);

const isArrayContains = arr.some(containsProps)

console.log('isArrayContains: ', isArrayContains);
```

Answer (score 1):

It easy to do with `lodash#has` method:

```
let hasProps = _.has(arr, '[0].satisfied') && _.has(arr, '[0].onSaleSince');
```

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "id": 30,
    "satisfied": false,
    "onSaleSince":"1 day"
  }
];

let hasProps = _.has(arr, '[0].satisfied') && _.has(arr, '[0].onSaleSince');
console.log(hasProps);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = [{
  id: 30,
  satisfied: false,
  onSaleSince: "1 day"
}, {
  id: 30,
  satisfied: false,
  onSaleUntil: "1 day"
}];

console.log(
  'Does every object in array has both `id` and `satisfied`?',
  a.every(x => 'id' in x && 'satisfied' in x)
);

console.log(
  'Is there any object in array which has both both `id` and `onSaleUntil`?',
  a.some(x => 'id' in x && 'onSaleUntil' in x)
);

console.log(
  'Does every object in array has at least one property of `onSaleSince` and `onSaleUntil`?',
  a.every(x => 'onSaleSince' in x || 'onSaleUntil' in x)
);
```